# Test that ndb entity was put to data store

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, transactions, app-engine-ndb

I've been bit by a bug where I am not properly checking that an entity was put to the data store.  It gets particularly confusing with transactions and the in-context cache and memcache.

Consider this entity where the intent of each method is to increment `n` and save the entity to the data store:

```
class MyEntity(ndb.Model):
    n = ndb.IntegerProperty()

    def inc(self):
        self.n += 1
        # self.put() # oops, forgot to put the entity

    @staticmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def inc_trans(key):
        x = key.get()
        x.n += 1
        # x.put() # oops, forgot to put the entity
```

and these unit tests:

```
def testInc(self):
    x = MyEntity(n=0)
    x.put()
    x.inc()
    x = x.key.get()
    self.assertEqual(x.n, 1)

def testIncTrans(self):
    x = MyEntity(n=0)
    x.put()
    MyEntity.inc_trans(x.key)
    x = x.key.get()
    self.assertEqual(x.n, 1)
```

What should I add to these tests to make sure that the entities have actually been saved to the data store?  (I.e., that we are not checking values stored in the in-context cache or memcache?)  Is it sufficient to add

```
ndb.get_context().clear_cache()
```

to the unit tests after the calls to `inc` and `inc_trans`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a little more research, I found that we can force `get` to not use any caches like this:

```
x = x.key.get(use_cache=False, use_memcache=False)
```

Using the no-cached get in tests seems like the way to go.